# Convergence radius: $R = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {\mid a_n \mid} {\mid a_{n+1} \mid}$ (incl. $\infty$) when $R = 0$ and Ratio test

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have read the following proof of a theorem in a textbook of mine, and I've been wondering why the proof holds when $$R = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {\mid a_n \mid} {\mid a_{n+1} \mid} = 0$$

The proof seems to be right given that $R \neq 0$ since it shows that every $z \in \mathbb C$ with $\mid z-a\mid > R$ fails to make the power series converge. But it doesn't say anything when $R=0$ ?

> Let $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n (z-a)^n$ be a power series and suppose $a_n \neq 0$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$. If the limit $R = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {\mid a_n \mid} {\mid a_{n+1} \mid}$ exists (incl. $\infty$), then $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n (z-a)^n$ has radius of convergence $R$.

Proof: When $z \neq a$ by the assumptions: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {\mid a_{n+1}(z-a)^{n+1}\mid} {\mid a_{n}(z-a)^n \mid}=\frac {\mid z-a \mid} R$. It then follows from the ratio test that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n (z-a)^n$ converges when $\frac {\mid z-a \mid} R < 1 \Rightarrow z-a < R$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n (z-a)^n$ diverges when $\frac {\mid z-a \mid} R > 1 \Rightarrow z-a > R$. This implies that $R$ must be the radius of convergence for the power series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n (z-a)^n$.

Also, I've been wondering why in the proof of the **ratio test** for convergence of series, why it is only stated for $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {\mid a_{n+1}\mid} {\mid a_n \mid} > 1$ and $< 1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $R = 0$, you can either read

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lvert a_{n+1}(z-a)^{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_n(z-a)^n\rvert} = \frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{R}$$

as stating that the absolute values of the quotients converges to infinity ($\frac{x}{0} = \infty$ for $x > 0$), or you can avoid infinity by replacing $R$ with any constant $0 < c < \lvert z-a\rvert$, which suffices to see that the terms of the power series don't converge to $0$.

Concerning the last question about the quotient criterion: It is because the case of limit $=1$ is ambiguous. Then the series might converge - $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ - or diverge - $\sum \frac1n$.

Comment: So what you are saying is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lvert a_{n+1}(z-a)^{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_n(z-a)^n\rvert} = \frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{R}$$ for $z \neq a$ implies that the limit doesn't exists when $R = 0$ since we can make the quotient arbitrarily large. So the terms $a_n$ in the sequence doesn't converge, in fact they grow arbitrarily large.

But does this imply that the only point of converge might be $0$ and that the radius of converge is in fact $0$ ??? What if $z$ is chosen very close to $a$ - then $(z-a)^n \rightarrow 0$ right ? and then the ...

Comment: power series might converge for $z > 0$ nonetheless ?

Comment: Ohh: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lvert a_{n+1}(z-a)^{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_n(z-a)^n\rvert} = \frac{\lvert z-a\rvert}{R}$$ implies the terms on the series doesn't converge to $0$ since the modulus increase arbitrarily using the fact that $R \rightarrow 0$ and $|z-a|$ is constant. And we can then imply the theorem that says a series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent if and only if $a_n \rightarrow 0$ ??

Comment: Convergence to infinity is more than just "has no finite limit". For any given bound, _all_ ratios from some point on are larger than the bound. And $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert}{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert} = 0$$ does not only mean that $\lvert a_n\rvert$ grows without bound, it means _it grows faster than any geometric progression_. And that means the growth cannot be compensated by multiplying with (the geometric progression) $(z-a)^n$.

Comment: Re latest comment: In the last sentence, not "if and only if". $a_n \to 0$ is a **necessary** condition, but not sufficient for the convergence of the series. The first part of that comment is exactly the point, the terms $a_n(z-a)^n$ don't converge to $0$ (in fact they grow very fast), thus the series cannot converge.